# Could not locate Clojure resource on classpath

Tags: java, clojure, leiningen, counterclockwise

I am trying to access some of my clojure functions in my Java code (I am using Eclipse and CounterClockWise). Firstly, I was not sure how to do it? But then I found some answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15071622/how-to-access-clojure-functions-in-java).

I am using `clojure.lang.RT package` for calling `.clj` files in my Java code. While naming namespaces, `.clj` files proper conventions has been followed like `ns test.clojure.core` is in `test.clojure` package where-in core is `.clj` file. Also upon following some information, I have added java-source-path (i.e. java-source-path `src/test/java`) and source-path (i.e. source-path `src/test/clojure`) in my `project.clj`.

But, when I run my Java file following error is given - a) `Could not locate Clojure resource on classpath` b)  `Attempting to call unbound fn`.

Please if anyone in community could help me (assuming I am absolute beginner) through detailed procedure or tutorial I would be grateful, as only information I could get (for using `clojure.lang.RT`) is very little.

Looking forward to get a complete answer to end my frustration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using `RT.loadResourceScript` which is causing the proble. 
You can try out something like this:

```
//Load the namespace 
    RT.var("clojure.core","eval").invoke(RT.var("clojure.core","read-string").invoke("(use 'test.clojure.core)"));

//Find a function in namespace
    IFn fn = (IFn)RT.var("test.clojure.core","hello");

//Call that function
    fn.invoke();
```

Comment: Will try that. BTW is there any proper documentation and/or tutorial for the same.

Comment: Hi Ankur, I tried for the following clojure code:
**'(ns test.clojure.core)
(defn hello-world [x]
  (str "Hello "x))'** and Java code:
**'RT.var("clojure.core","eval").invoke(RT.var("clojure.core","hello-world").invoke("(use 'test.clojure.core)"));
   IFn fn = (IFn)RT.var("test.clojure.core","hello");
   Object result = fn.invoke();'**


And now I am getting this error: **Attempting to call unbound fn: #'clojure.core/hello-world**

Comment: `RT.var("clojure.core","eval").invoke(RT.var("clojure.core","read-string").invo‌​ke("(use 'test.clojure.core)")); IFn fn = (IFn)RT.var("test.clojure.core","hello-world"); Object result = fn.invoke("test");`

Comment: There aren't many tutorials on this topic. Your best friend is the read and eval technique shown in the code and the RT.var method. I would suggest you to go through RT class code on github as that is the best way to understand things

Comment: Hi Ankur, I don't know how to thank you. Thanks a ton for ending my frustration. Just last question - all I did in this was done in same project could my clojure functions be called from another java project using JAR files maybe. Please help me in this last thing. Once again many thanks.

Comment: Yes, if your clojure project JAR file is in the classpath while executing the java JAR file, the java code can use the same approach as shown above. Remember `(use 'mynamespace)` is like `import mypackage` in java, you just need to have the proper classpath set